# How to prevent WinDbg from attaching to specific child processes?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm debugging a script in WinDbg with `.childdbg 1`. (The script runs various test cases of software in infinite loop. This way I catch rare crashes.)

I need not to attach to specific child processes (for performance reasons and because they are third-party and crash often).

If I could specify them by process name, that would solve my problem. If you can propose an other debugger that can do what I need, I will be grateful.

NOTE: Configuring debugger to attach to specific processes via GFlags is not a solution in this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

If you have activated `.childdbg 1`, you can make use of `sxe cpr`. With the `-c` switch, you can execute a command. Something like `.if (yourcondition) {.detach} .else {g}` could help.

Perhaps the `cpr:ProcessName` option is really helpful for you. It supports wildcard filters. I've never used it until now, see *Controlling Exceptions and Events* in WinDbg help.

I used the following .NET program to perform a test:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attach and press Enter");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
    Process.Start("calc.exe");
    Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
    Process.Start("calc.exe");
    Console.WriteLine("Started 4 processes");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I started the program under the debugger and did the following:

```
0:004> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged
0:004> sxe -c ".detach;g" cpr:calc
0:004> g
...
77da12fb cc              int     3
1:009> |
   0    id: 1fe0    create  name: DebugChildProcesses.exe
.  1    id: f60 child   name: notepad.exe
1:009> g
...
77da12fb cc              int     3
2:011> |
   0    id: 1fe0    create  name: DebugChildProcesses.exe
   1    id: f60 child   name: notepad.exe
.  2    id: 1d68    child   name: notepad.exe
2:011> g
```

As you can see, the debugger is attached to Notepad only.

Unfortunately, you cannot use multiple `sxe cpr:process` commands. Whenever you use it again, it will overwrite the previous settings.

In that case, you need to use a generic CPR handler and do the rest inside the command. In my tests, `!peb` did not work well at that time, so I couldn't use it. However, WinDbg has already switched to that process, therefore `|.` gives us the process name along with some other information. To extract the process name only, `.foreach /pS 6 (token {|.}) { .echo ${token}}` worked for me.

With this, you can build trickier commands like

```
.foreach /pS 6 (token {|.}) { 
    .if    (0==$scmp("${token}","notepad.exe")) {.echo "It's Notepad!"} 
    .elsif (0==$scmp("${token}","calc.exe"))    {.echo "Do some math!"} 
}
```

(formatted for readability, remove the line breaks)

When you try to combine this with `sxe`, you run into some nasty string escaping problems. Replace all quotes inside your command by `\"` to make it work:

```
sxe -c"
    .foreach /pS 6 (token {|.}) { 
        .if (0==$scmp(\"${token}\",\"notepad.exe\")) {.echo \"It's Notepad!\"} 
        .elsif (0==$scmp(\"${token}\",\"calc.exe\")) {.echo \"Do some math!\"} 
    }
" cpr
```

(formatted for readability, remove the line breaks)

Now you can do whatever you like, e.g. `.detach` or `.kill`, just replace the `.echo` command in above example. You can execute several commands by separating them via semicolon (`;`) as usual.

BTW: If you use `sxe cpr`, you might perhaps want to turn off the initial process breakpoint by `sxd ibp`.

Comment: The debugger seems to accept the syntax like: `.if (<process name> == 'proc1.exe' || <process name> == 'proc2.exe' || ...) {.detach};g`. But what is the command to get **<process name>** ? And can you provide example on use of option `cpr:ProcessName` that you referred? I could not find anything like that in WinDbg help.

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account: I added an example for both

Comment: Note: you can use cmd.exe for debugging of such WinDbg snippets. No need to write new application.

Comment: I remember I updated this answer with working example. I just came here to copy it, because I need to debug process tree again. Did you delete my modification? Not good of you,

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account: I was asked by SO to review your edit. I have integrated most of your proposals, except `.kill` and `.detach`. Instead I have pointed out that these can be used. The answer in general should also be helpful for other visitors, so it should keep the example style and not be tailored only for you.

Comment: In general, you cannot rely that information on SO never changes. Anyone with a reputation of >2000 can edit the answer and it will immediately be approved. Other than that, the question and its answer might (although unlikely) even be deleted. So if the answer is useful to you, it's better to keep a copy yourself.

Comment: I will post my example in additional answer later then, so that it will be helpful for other visitors. But it's a flaw in SO that a version is permanently deleted from edit history if it was not approved by author of answer.

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account: It needn't be approved by the author. It can also be approved by the community (via the review queue). I'm a bit sad that you unaccepted the answer due to this.